# Ionic 2 plugin not found Issue

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic2, cordova-nativestorage

I'm using the latest version of Ionic 2. here is my ionic package.json

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "build",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^1.1.6",
    "ionic-native": "^2.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^0.0.30",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "description": "SSRetail: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

I installed a plugin "cordova-plugin-nativestorage", imported the "NativeStorage" from ionic-native and used in the project.

Snippet:

```
setConnectionInfo() {
    NativeStorage.setItem('myitem', { property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue' })
      .then(
      () => console.log('Stored item!'),
      error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
      );
  }
```

but when i run it in my emulator using "ionic run android -c -l", i'm getting an error that the plugin is not found, install the plugin!!

```
LAUNCH SUCCESS

0 882136 log Hello ConnectionService Provider

1 882133 warn Native: tried calling t.setItem, but the t plugin is not installed.

2 882134 warn Install the t plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova—plugin—nativestorage' 
3 882261 error Error storing item, plugin_not_installed
4 882261 log DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER, 195, ms

Ionic server commands, enter: 
rezta t or m to restart the client app from the root
```

Please advice. Thank you. and for some reason, i added the plugin but the package.json file doesn't get updated with the new cordova plugin.

ionic info

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Framework Version: 2.6.9-rc.6—261616131811
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.6—beta.1
OS: windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v6.2.9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error image you've provided, it seems you tried to use the function **before the deviceready has fired**. wrap your method calls with **platform.ready()** and it should work. cheers.